# How would an is_instantiable type trait be defined?

Tags: c++, instance, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Let's consider a type trait of the following form:

```
template <class T>
struct is_instantiable
{
    static constexpr bool value = /* something */;
};

template <class T>
inline constexpr bool is_instantiable_v = is_instantiable<T>::value;
```

which would detect whether an entity of type `T` can be instantiated.

Currently the standard library already has traits like `is_constructible` (but it requires the arguments from which the object is constructed). I am wondering:

- Whether an `is_instantiable` type trait would be any useful?
- Would it allow things that are currently problematic with `is_constructible`?
- How would it even be defined/implemented (it's ok if it requires some compiler magic)?

Currently I have no idea whether such a thing would be any useful? (if you have any interesting use case in mind where `is_constructible` is limiting, that would be awesome).

Comment: Interesting, but ultimately too broad a question. Asking how something can be useful usually has that trait.

Comment: This is asking how the question itself can be useful and defined, which is kind of circular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about this conversely.
I'm assuming that by something that cannot be instantiated you mean something that doesn't have a single valid constructor and is not an in-built type.
As far as I see, the only way you can give anything a type, an instance of which cannot be constructed, is by casting (using a `reinterpret_cast`?).
Writing code like that is a horrible decision, in my opinion, but I suppose it could theoretically occur.

I guess, a usage case would be a situation where you are expecting that an object you are dealing with might have been produced by such a cast, and you want to know whether that's the case.

It's definitely an esoteric question to ask the compiler, and I don't see how this information can be used productively, nor how you could implement this trait.